# why is it giving index error out of range although i am almost sure I am in range?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i was trying to fill a list with inputs, but it gave me index out of range
although the index is starting from zero, as far as i know we don't have to specify the length of a list in python.

```
inputs = input("Enter the number of inputs: ")
lists = []
k = 0
while k<inputs:
    lists[k]= input()
    k+=1
```

Comment: You have 0 elements. Nothing is in range. Did you meant to use `lists.append()` perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am trying to write this without any of the methods.

Comment: because you can only index elements *already in the list*. Your list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your list before using indexes of it:

```
lists = [0] * int(inputs)
```

And then you can use your code

Comment: you are the man! I will mark this as a solution as soon as I can, I was looking for a way without using any of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are creating an **empty** list with `lists = []` and then accessing an element of this empty list. This is the cause of the `IndexError`.

Appending with `lists.append()` helps you avoid index errors like this one. You generally want to use indexing when *accessing elements* and **not** when *populating the list*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.append()` to add an element to the end of the list:

```
while k<inputs:
    lists.append(input())
    k+=1
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
lists = [input() for _ in range(inputs)]
```

Comment: isn't there a way without using one of the methods?

Comment: @xixhxix: Yes, but what's your motivation?

Comment: I am writing this for someone who hasn't gone to that place yet

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: Initialize `lists` as an empty list and then append the input with the `+=` operand.

```
lists = []
k = 0
while k < inputs:
    lists += [input()]
    k+=1
```